# Освобождение памяти в C

Tags: c, память

Допустим, загрузил данные в память единым блоком

```
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char* title;
} dbrow;

const int ALLOC_SIZE = 4096;

int dbindex = 0;
int dbsize = 0;
int dballoc = 0;

dbrow  *DBS = NULL;
dbrow  *DBSTEMP = NULL;

static void load_dbs_row( char * s)
{
    int n = 0;
    char * ptr1;
    ptr1 = s;

    char * tok = strchr( ptr1, '|' );
    while( tok )
    {
        *tok = 0;
        switch (n) {
               case 0:
                      if (atoi(ptr1) == 0) { return ; }
                      dbindex = atoi(ptr1);
                      while (dbindex >= dballoc) {
                         dballoc = dballoc + ALLOC_SIZE;
                         DBSTEMP = (dbrow *) realloc(DBS, (dballoc+1) * sizeof (dbrow));
                         if (DBSTEMP == NULL) {
                            free(DBS);
                            printf("Not enough memory for db\n");
                            return ;
                         }
                         DBS = DBSTEMP;
                      }
                      DBS[dbindex].id = dbindex;
                    break;
               case 1:DBS[dbindex].title = ptr1;break;
        }
        ptr1 = tok + 1;        
        tok = strchr( ptr1, '|' );
        n++;
    }

    if (*ptr1) 
    {
        switch (n) {
               case 1:DBS[dbindex].title = ptr1;break;                
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    int i,a;
    char * newline;
    char * ptr;
    char *content = NULL;
    content = (char *)malloc(50);
    strcpy (content,"1|raz\n11|dva\n21|tri\n31|shestb\n5000|test\n|||\n||\n|\n");    
    ptr = content;

    newline = strchr( ptr, '\n' );
    while( newline )
    {
        *newline = 0;
        load_dbs_row( ptr );
        ptr = newline + 1;
        newline = strchr( ptr, '\n' );
        dbsize++;
    }
    if( *ptr )
    {
        load_dbs_row( ptr );
        dbsize++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

В данном примере, данные не перемещаются в памяти, а устанавливается указатель структуры dbrow.title на соответсвующий титл. Для освобождения памяти нужно освободить переменную content (это освободит все dbrow.title) и элементы массива DBS.

Собственно впрос, если после загрузки и разбора массива таким способом, необходимо добавить ещё несколько элементов. Для этого нужно зарезервировать память для dbrow и dbrow.title, **и dbrow.title не будет уже частью content**.

```
dballoc++;
DBS[dballoc] = malloc(sizeof(dbrow));
DBS[dballoc].title = malloc(10); //Здесь память для титла уже не является частью content;
...
```

Как мне потом освободить память, можно ли освободить каждый dbrow.title, который является частью content? Наверно нельзя, и нужно освобождать content, а все элементы, которые добавились потом, запоминать в отдельной структуре, и тоже освобождать.

Comment: @cromax, попробуйте выделить из кода в вопросе, не который ссылаетесь, релевантные этому вопросу фрагменты (включая описания типов и часть кода, заполняющего структуры данных) и разместить их здесь.

Comment: Наверно при, освобождении памяти, можно проверить, является ли память очередного title частью content:

for ( j = 0; j <= dballoc; ++j) {

if (((int)DBS[j].title < (int)content) && ((int)DBS[j].title >(int)content)) {

free(DBS[j]);

}

}

free(content);

free(DBS);

Comment: В частном случае (один раз используете `content`) можно, для более общей реализации - нехорощо (легко запутаться).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, Вы правы.

Если хотите сделать единообразно, то при разборе **`content`** в `load_dbs_row()` вместо

```
DBS[dbindex].title = ptr1;
```

можно написать

```
DBS[dbindex].title = strdup(ptr1);
```

`strdup()` выделяет память и копирует туда строку (завершающуюся 0-ем).

Естественно, при этом растет расход памяти и время выполнения, но упрощается код для освобождения памяти. Возможен другой подход - заведите в структуре `dbrow` флаг, который показывает выделена ли память, адресуемая .title динамически.

Comment: А система (centos, win) гарантирует выделение непрерывного блока памяти, чтобы условие 

    (((int)DBS[j].title < (int)content) || ((int)DBS[j].title >(int)content + contentlen ))

сработало?
И можно ли вообще, не очищать память, система очистит ее сама, по завершении программы?

Comment: Гарантирует :) . Иначе бы к массивам и строкам нельзя было бы обращаться через []

Comment: Пришлось переоткрыть вопрос.

--

Хочу только добавить, что приводить адреса к `int` **неправильно**. В 64-бит системе int по прежнему 32 бита. Это раз. А два - это то, что старшие адреса, приведенные к целому **со знаком** будут представлены **отрицательными числами**.



Приводить для сравнения на больше-меньше надо к `size_t` или `unsigned long`.

Comment: Счас уже везде х64, обязательно учту.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам так хочется заморочиться с указателями на общий кусок памяти, то да, можно применить хак, который вы написали в комментарии. Только

```
endPtr = content + strlen(content);
...
if (((int)DBS[j].title < (int)content) || ((int)DBS[j].title >(int)endPtr)) { free(DBS[j]); }
```

Comment: Ну значит у вас будет ещё одна проблема - как определить конец content :)

Answer (score 0):

Написать нормально персер, аля как-то так:

```
dbrow_t parse(char * p) {
  dbrow_t dbrow = (dbrow_t){ .id = atoi(p), .title = (strchr(p, '|') + 1) };
  if(atoi(p) && isalpha(*(dbrow.title)))
    return (dbrow_t){ .id = atoi(p), .title = (strchr(p, '|') + 1) };
  return (dbrow_t){0};
}

void print_dbrow(dbrow_t dbrow) {
  if(dbrow.id && isalpha(*(dbrow.title)))
    fprintf(stderr, "id = %u, title = %s\n", dbrow.id, dbrow.title);
}

int main(void) {
    char * content = strcpy(malloc(50), "1|raz\n11|dva\n21|tri\n31|shestb\n5000|test\n|||\n||\n|\n");
    char *p = strtok(content, "\n");
    print_dbrow(parse(p));
    do {
      print_dbrow(parse(strtok('\0', "\n")));      
    } while(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Можно конечно как-то так: http://pastebin.com/dsrsn9Fx - я тут заодно накидал примерно как это должено выглядеть.

Темболее у тебя будут плюсы - тебе проще нормально запилить нормальные контексты.

Как выделять память? Вот так:

```
typedef struct {
  char * begin, * end, * curr;
} title_stack_t;

inline title_stack_t _stack_init(uint64_t create_size) {
  char * p = malloc(create_size);
  return (title_stack_t){ .begin = p, .end = (p + create_size), .curr = p};
}

inline title_stack_t _stack_resize(title_stack_t cont, uint64_t new_size) {
  char * old_begin = cont.begin;
  uint64_t old_offset = (cont.curr - old_begin);
  char * new_begin = realloc(old_begin, new_size);  
  return (title_stack_t){ .begin = new_begin, .end = (new_begin + new_size), .curr = (new_begin + old_offset)};
}

inline char * _stack_alloc(title_stack_t * cont, uint64_t strlen) {
  char * new_curr = (cont->curr + strlen);
  if(new_curr > cont->end) *cont = _stack_resize(*cont, ((new_curr - cont->begin) << 1));
  char * ret = cont->begin; cont->curr += strlen;
  return ret;
}

inline void _stack_dealloc(title_stack_t cont) {
  free(cont.begin);
}
```

Поменяй там uint64_t на size_t, либо на uint_fast32_t;

Дабавляй стек в контекст - он бесконечный, юзай его вместо маллока - удаляется потом за один _stack_dealloc() - удаляется вся память, которую ты через него выделял.

Да и вообще - надо осилить как работает память, а потом уже писать.